# Is it possible to remove CMFCRibbonPanel from CMFCRibbonCategory?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I'm looking for a trick to remove an `CMFCRibbonPanel` from `CMFCRibbonCategory`. There is just the `AddPanel()` function in the `CMFCRibbonCategory`, but no `RemovePanel()`.

Do I really need to rebuild my whole `CMFCRibbonCategory` to do this?

Just for clarification, what I want is to remove the panel itself from the category and not the elements from the panel.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I did end up rebuilding the category from scratch. In the `CMFCRibbonCategory` source code (look for `afxribboncategory.cpp`) there is no apparent way to remove a panel from the panels array.

Comment: Yea, I also end up by this solution! I added connect request! Please vote here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=419881

Comment: Me too. But I didn't really mind because I wanted to remove ALL panels, so I just added a new category and removed the old one. But still not as good as CMFCCategory::RemoveAllPanels would have been...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about `CMFCRibbonPanel` and `CMFCRibbonCategory`. After seeing the class declaration in MSDN I thought you can get a reference to `CMFCRibbonPanel` from `CMFCRibbonCategory` and call `CMFCRibbonPanel::RemoveAll` on the pointer.

```
CMFCRibbonCategory *pCategory = m_wndRibbonBar.GetCategory(0);

if (pCategory)
{
     CMFCRibbonPanel *pPanel = pCategory->GetPanel(0);

     if (pPanel)
     {
        pPanel->RemoveAll();
        m_wndRibbonBar.AdjustSizeImmediate();
     }
}
```

Comment: I want to remove pPanel itself and not the elements in the panel.
BTW: You should use

while (pPanel->GetCount())
{
VERIFY(pPanel->Remove(0));
}
insted of pPanel->RemoveAll();

see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=377527&wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: I know this is like 3 years ago, anyway thanks for helping me in the future.